# Incorrect regex identification using pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I wrote a small program for data type detection using regular expressions. I worked on this project in the past and got a lot of help from this wonderful community. I was going to use this code for a current project but I found that I am having an issue with properly identifying floats.

The objective of this code is to read in csv's as strings, identify the data type for each column, then convert the column to that data type. The example CSV I am testing is here:
[image]

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate
from datetime import datetime
from pandas.compat import StringIO
import re

df = pd.read_csv(pathname, dtype=str)
df = df.reset_index()
del df['index']
lst = list(df.columns.values)
numrows = df.shape[0]
numcols = df.shape[1]
col = 0
row = 0
date_count = []
int_count = []
str_count = []
boolean_count = []
float_count = []
time_count = []
dict = {}
keys = []
vals = []
variable_1 = 0
while col < numcols:
    while row < numrows:
        var2 = str(df.ix[row][col])
        # How to match all the data types:
        str_pattern = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', var2)
        str_count = str_count + [str_pattern]
        int_pattern = re.findall(r'(?:\s|^)(\d+)(?:\s|$)', var2)
        int_count = int_count + [int_pattern]
        float_pattern = re.findall(r'^\d+\.\d+$', var2)
        float_count = float_count + [float_pattern]
        #boolean_pattern = re.findall(r'TRUE|FALSE|True|False|true|false|t|f|T|F', var2)
        boolean_pattern = re.findall(r'^TRUE$|^FALSE$|^True$|^False$|^true$|^false$|^t$|^f$|^T$|^F$', var2)
        boolean_count = boolean_count + [boolean_pattern]
        date_pattern = re.findall(r'(\d\d?|[a-zA-Z]{2,8})([:/-])(\d\d?)\2(\d{2,4})', var2)
        date_count = date_count + [date_pattern]
        time_pattern = re.findall(r'(\d{1,2})(?:[\:]{1})(\d{1,2})(?:[\:]{1})(\d{1,2})', var2)
        time_count = time_count + [time_pattern]
        # How to clear out all the empty values in the array
        str_count = [x for x in str_count if x != []]
        int_count = [x for x in int_count if x != []]
        float_count = [x for x in float_count if x != []]
        boolean_count = [x for x in boolean_count if x != []]
        date_count = [x for x in date_count if x != []]

        row = row + 1
    # Changing the column data types
    if len(int_count) == len(str_count):
        df[lst[col]] = pd.to_numeric(df[lst[col]], errors='coerce', downcast='integer')
    if len(float_count) == len(str_count):
        df[lst[col]] = pd.to_numeric(df[lst[col]], errors='coerce', downcast='float')
    if len(boolean_count) == len(str_count):
        df[lst[col]] = df[lst[col]].astype('bool')
    if len(date_count) == len(str_count):
        df[lst[col]] = pd.to_datetime(df[lst[col]], errors='coerce')

    del str_count[:]
    del int_count[:]
    del float_count[:]
    del boolean_count[:]
    del date_count[:]

    # Converting any column that has type object into a string
    df.update(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.object]).astype(str))
    col = col + 1
    row = 0

#Creating Key to create dictionary
keys = list(df.columns.values)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Output:

[image]

When I run this code and place the example CSV path name into the read_csv, everything runs properly but for some reason, the "Address" column is being returned as type Float. I went to regex101.com and tried playing around my regular expression and it is working properly.

Any help would be great!

Here is the example data :

```
Date,Name,Address,Age,Married
10/10/10,Alice,123 Main Street,21,FALSE
12/12/12,Bob,830 East Jefferson Street,30,TRUE
11/11/11,Rohin,6616 Majestic Way,21,FALSE
```

Comment: Could you paste the example data rather than an image? It makes it easier for us to copy and test.

Comment: For starters, your float pattern is missing start and stop anchors (it should be `^\d+\.\d+$`). But that’s just the first step. It won’t work on valid `float` input.

Comment: @FHTMitchell How can I add data to stack overflow? I have never done that before.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I added the start and stop anchors, but that didn't seem to solve the problem. It isn't an issue when I run this on regex101 and test it with the address column's row individually. But when it is loaded into the dataframe for some reason, this error seems to be happening.

Comment: Copy and paste into the question. It's a csv which is just text.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Added. Let me know if there is anything else I can do on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not identifying address as a float; it's identifying it as an integer, failing on `to_numeric`, and thus ignoring the `downcast`.  Try this:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Address'], errors='coerce', downcast='integer')
```

You'll see that what it returns is a column of NaN, with type `float64`.  You're matching all the addresses as integers because the columns all *contain* integers, and your integer regexp matches them since it's whitespace delimited.  If you didn't have that `errors='coerce'` you may have seen what was going on.

Edited: To clarify a bit more, what you need to do is edit your integer regexp so that it matches only if the entire field is an integer with optional leading or trailing whitespace.

```
re.findall(r'(^\s?\d+\s?$)'
```

This will match on '123' or ' 123 ' but not '123 Main Street'.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. So if I were to modify my integer regex to not include any whitespace before or after, could that solve the problem? Also, could I do that by changing /s to /S in the 3rd group? Quite new to this.

Comment: Edit: I modified the regex to just this and it seems to be only capture the integers, but the issue still persists: ^\S\d\S+

Comment: What you need to do is edit the integer regexp so that the field consists only of an integer optionally with leading or trailing whitespace.  I've added this to the answer above.